# Gaussian Elimination No Pivoting

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, gaussian

I am trying to write a program that can do Gaussian Elimination without partial pivoting. This is what I have so far, I know I'm messing something up but I can't seem to figure out what. It keeps printing out the same matrix it started with and not the 0s with 1s in the diagonal. Any help appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import math

#A = np.array([[1,2,-1],[5,2,2],[-3,5,-1]])
#b = np.array([[2,9,1]])
A = np.array([[8,-2,-1,0,0],[-2,9,-4,-1,0],[-1,-3,7,-1,2],[0,-4,-2,12,-5],[0,0,-7,-3,15]])
b = np.array([[5],[2],[0],[1],[5]])

def forward_elim(A, b, n):
#calculates the forward part of Gaussian elimination.

    for row in range(0, n-1):
        for i in range(row+1, n):
            factor = A[i,row] / A[row,row]
            for j in range(row, n):
                A[i,j] = A[i,j] - factor * A[row,j]

            b[i] = b[i] - factor * b[row]

        print("A = \n%s and b = %s" % (A,b))
    return A, b

def back_sub(A, b, n):
#back substitution and returns result

    x = np.zeros((n,1))
    x[n-1] = b[n-1] / A[n-1, n-1]
    for row in range(n-2, -1, -1):
        sums = b[row]
        for j in range(row+1, n):
            sums = sums - A[row,j] * x[j]
        x[row] = sums / A[row,row]
    return x

def gauss_elim(A, b):
#performs gaussian elimination without pivoting

    n = A.shape[0]
    #checks for zero diagonal elements
    if any(np.diag(A)==0):
        raise ZeroDivisionError(("Can't divide by 0")) #raise used to raise exception

    A, b = forward_elim(A, b, n)
    return back_sub(A, b, n)

print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the given code it is not clear whether you effectively call the function `gauss_elim(A, b)`.

To help finding out was is going on, try stepping through a really simple example. Best with the help of a debugger, or by printing out intermediate values. Follow the same example writing the steps on a sheet of paper.

A simple example could be:

```
A = np.array([[2,4],[3,9]])
b = np.array([[2,30]])
```

One of the problems is that you declare `b` as a `1xn` matrix, but later use it as just a vector. A solution can be to declare `b` as a vector:

```
b = np.array([2,30])
```